# DataGridView row initialisation in excel-import method

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, import, row

I'm a fresh 2-week old C# "programmer" so pardon my mistakes (but point them out :) ) and I have a problem with a simple method that imports first sheet of an excel document into data grid view. This is my code as faar :

```
public void OpenFile(string filePath)
    {   
        try 
        {
            //Clear data grid view and refresh. 
            gridData.Rows.Clear(); 
            gridData.Refresh();

            //Components declaration/initialization.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            DataGridViewRow draftRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell draftCell;

            //Opening Excel file.
            workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

            //Geting range of excel file.
            range = worksheet.UsedRange;

            //Sheet extraction into 2-dimensional array.
            object[,] valueArray = (object[,])range.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

            //Loading values into data grid view from array without header.
            for(int row = 2; row < range.Rows.Count; row++)
            {   
                for(int column = 1; column < range.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    draftCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                    draftCell.Value = valueArray[row,column].ToString();
                    draftRow.Cells.Add(draftCell);
                }
                //HERE IS THE PROBLEM :(
                gridData.Rows.Add(draftRow);
                draftRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            }
            //Closing excel app.
            workbook.Close(true, null, null);
            excelApp.Quit();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }               
    }
```

My problem occurs at the point where I try to add my draftRow to gridData (my DataGridView object). I get a null-exception "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." , but I don't understand what could be wrong and how to fix it. A DataGridView object exists at this point.

I have a similar code in event onClick and it doesn't make any problems.

I'll be most appreciative for any piece of help in this matter.

**EDIT :** Due to my absentmindedness I completely forgot to incriment range for cells and rows in my both for-loops which ended with saving a row without last cell which is a null in this case. All in all it should look like this :

```
//Loading values into data grid view from array without header.
        for(int row = 2; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
        {   
            for(int column = 1; column <= range.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                draftCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                draftCell.Value = valueArray[row,column].ToString();
                draftRow.Cells.Add(draftCell);
            }
            gridData.Rows.Add(draftRow);
            draftRow = new DataGridViewRow();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to create DataGridViewColumn objects first? Also have you considered binding to a DataTable rather than writing the data directly to the gridview?

Comment: @Dan Yes I considered binding it to a DataTable and even did it (it should be way faster than what I'm doing), but I get new exceptions, so I'll stick to this one until optimisation. I'll update my code when I'm so faar :)